# Referencing an instance type of a child class in base class constructor parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm working on event-sourcing prototype in Typescript 3.4.2 and Node v.12.

It works well, but I want to avoid writing copy-pasted constructors and generics like `AbstractEvent<T>` for each type of event.

Is there a way to enable TS type-checking in parent class constructor, based on child class instance?

```js
abstract class AbstractEvent {

    // I want type system work here something like:
    // public constructor(data: InstanceType< typeof this >)

    public constructor(data: any) {
        for (const key in data) {
            this[key] = data[key];
        }
    }
}

class PackCreatedEvent extends AbstractEvent {
    public readonly id: string;
    public readonly title: string;

    // I want to avoid writing constructors for each event type
    // and also trying to avoid extra interfaces
    public constructor(data: PackCreatedEvent) {
        super(data);
    }
}

class UserCreatedEvent extends AbstractEvent {
    public readonly id: string;
    public readonly email: string;
}

// instantiating

const packCreatedEvent1 = new PackCreatedEvent({
    id: 'GSNV-FGHT-FGHF-HFTH',
    title: 'Apple',
});

const packCreatedEvent2 = new PackCreatedEvent({
    id: 'ABGF-FGHT-FGHF-HFTH',
    title: 'Banana',

    // uncomment to see error
    // someBadProperty: 'test',
});


const userCreatedEvent = new UserCreatedEvent({
    id: 'GSNV-FGHT-FGHF-HFTH',
    email: 'test@mail.com',

    // not a valid property
    // and not error because of 'any' in AbstractEvent.constructor
    someBadProperty: 'test',
});
```

Comment: Very interesting question. I wanted to say you could just use `data: AbstractEvent`, but then your `packCreatedEvent2` works even with the line uncommented. I want `data: typeof this` or `data: this` (trying for that [polymorphic `this`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types)), but those don't work, I tried them. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I tried all the possible variants of referencing `this` type in constructor arguments, but nothing is working :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Don't think there is a solution as OP wants. I know of no way to access the derived type from the base type (polymorphic `this` is not available in the constructor as you point out). The only alternate solutions I can think of is using a static method instead of `new` (with a static we can extract the target class) or making `AbstractEvent` generic and passing in the derived class `class PackCreatedEvent extends AbstractEvent<PackCreatedEvent> { .. }`  which I believe would be the simplest option. If Infloop can clarify why he objects to generics  maybe we can work something out.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Thanks for taking a look! It'll be interesting to see where this goes. Your generic approach does seem simplest -- no need to explciitly create the constructors, and just adding `<PackCreatedEvent>` to the `extends`.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - I guess we have to fudge the `this[key] = data[key]` part (`(this as any)[key] = data[key];`), but that seems acceptable (and unavoidable) here. Other than that, [works a treat](https://pastebin.com/7JRkGFnR).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, that is what I was thinking, the type assertion is unavoidable.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I am totally OK with generics, just wanted to find a way to write less code :-)

Comment: Infloop, the type parameter is at least not run-time code :) @T.J.Crowder you want to write it up or should I ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - You came up with it (kicking myself a bit for missing it), so all yours! :-)

Comment: @Infloop - The neat thing about Titian's solution is: A) It provides the type safety you were looking for; B) it's less typing overall (e.g., in the source code) because although you type the type parameter on the subclass, you don't type its constructor; and C) The emitted code doesn't need to have constructors in the subclasses. So not only didn't you have to type them, they aren't in the bundle either.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Friday night is when dad duties kick into full gear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way of accessing the derived class in the constructor. Polymorphic `this` is not accessible in the constructor, as has been pointed out in the comments.

The simplest option is to add a type parameter to `AbstractEvent`. The type parameter will be the class itself in the derived classes. The advantage of this is a solution that does not require any extra runtime code. No need for derived type constructors.

```
abstract class AbstractEvent<T extends AbstractEvent<any>> {
    public constructor(data: T) {
        for (const key in data) {
            this[key as any] = data[key];
        }
    }
}

class PackCreatedEvent extends AbstractEvent<PackCreatedEvent> {
    public readonly id: string;
    public readonly title: string;
}

class UserCreatedEvent extends AbstractEvent<UserCreatedEvent> {
    public readonly id: string;
    public readonly email: string;
}

const userCreatedEvent = new UserCreatedEvent({
    id: 'GSNV-FGHT-FGHF-HFTH',
    email: 'test@mail.com',

    // not a valid property
    // error now
    someBadProperty: 'test',
});
```